# Call function PhantomJs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm new in Java Script and i need help :)
I want to call function ( set_calendar_date() ) and then get page innerHTML.

```
<a onclick="set_calendar_date('1'); return false;" href="#">

<span>

    26/02 We

</span>
```

PhantomJs code :

```
page.open(url, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') 
{
            console.log('Unable to access network');
    } 
else 
{
    var events = page.evaluate(function () {
            // here i want to call set_calendar_date();
            return document.getElementById('fs').innerHTML;
        });
    var file= require('fs');
    file.write('results.txt',events,'w+');

phantom.exit();
}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the function `set_calendar_date` when executed will load content through ajax or do some processing to generate content. This content will be placed somewhere, possibly inside  an element with id `fs`.

Considering the asynchronous nature of this process, you can not directly return the `innerHTML` just after calling the function (you may either get the old data or nothing at all).

What I would suggest is to call the function inside evaluate

```
    page.evaluate(function () {
        set_calendar_date('1');
    });
```

Next, you need to understand the nature of the "update". Find an element that can help in programmatically determine that the update is complete or not-yet-complete. Say, for instance, if the `innherHTML` of the element with id `fs` is empty the content is not yet updated.

And then keep checking for change in the target element (vis, `fs`). You can keep checking this using `window.setInterval`.

The code can be similar to:

```
page.evaluate(function () {
   set_calendar_date('1');
});

var waiter = window.setInterval(function(){
  var fsContent = page.evaluate(function(){
     var elm = document.getElementById('fs');
     return elm && elm.innerHTML || false;
  });
  // if content is found
  if (fsContent !== false) {
     window.clearInterval(waiter);
     var file= require('fs');
     file.write('results.txt',fsContent,'w+');
  }

}, 300);
```

NOTE: This can be implemented with simpler code using CasperJS, a wrapper around PhantomJS. CasperJS provides a number of functions to do this easily like using `waitForSelectorTextChange()` or `waitFor()`, `waitForSelector()` or `waitWhileSelector()` etc.